# How can I get an saved input for an variable in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm having problems while trying to make a launcher for source ports of the game Doom. One of the features that I wanted to add is adding sourceports from their EXE files. To do that, I need to make a menu for adding them. When I do it manually like this it works.

```
set /p choosedDoom="selection:"
choosedDoom=%choosedDoom:z=Z%
if "%choosedDoom%" == "Z" (
cls
D: && cd Games\0RETRO\DOOM\ZDOOM
zdoom.exe
exit
)
```

But I want to make the locations changeable and get the input for the directories then save this locations for feature use. Then when you open the program later it should automatically know the directory and the exe.

```
echo please enter the directory
REM in this place you have to enter the directory ex.(drive:\dirname\game dirname)
echo please select the exe file in the directory
REM in this place you chose the exe file in that directory ex.(gameexefile)

if "%choosedDoom%" == "X" (
cls
drive: && cd dirname\game dirname
gameexefile.exe
exit
)
```

And i know im realy bad with explaining what i want to do so i made this [concept pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m8bO.jpg)

And this is the [full code](http://www5.zippyshare.com/v/btowj6G3/file.html)

So is what i want is possible?

Comment: What do you want to do? you are not clear. do you want multiple locations as in where the doom directories are??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to use `choice` to select the directory. This will not store new directories for you, unless you add another choice option to do `set /p` which will prompt for a new location, and store it to file, but then you need to change the concept completely below and read each option from file.

```
@echo off
echo a - "D:\Some Dir\Doom"
echo b - "C:\Program Files\Doom2"
echo c - "F:\Doom\Doom"
choice /c abc /m "Select your destination: "
if %errorlevel% == 1 set "location=D:\Some Dir\Doom"
if %errorlevel% == 2 set "location=C:\Program Files\Doom2"
if %errorlevel% == 3 set "location=F:\Doom\Doom"

cd /d "%location%"
zdoom.exe
exit
```